# (Azure Data Factory) Agregate doesn't work if column doesn't exists

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm working on this Data Flow :

[image: Data_Flow]

How to use the Agregate on a column that doesn't exists yet ?
Because the Data Flow has never been launched.

I must do this in one Data Flow (Not with one Data Flow to initialize the Delta Lake, and another to insert new rows).

Comment: Have you tried to add a derive column activity before your aggregation with [iifNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#iifnull) to create some default value if the column does not exists?

Comment: It doesn't works. because the column doesn't exists.

Comment: If you have the knowledge about the target schema, you might want to manually adding the columns and datatypes into the `typeProperties` field of the [dataset JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services#dataset-json)

Answer (score 0):

You are using different source to add the column and then using it later. It's better if you use the derived column transformation before using the aggregate and then move forward.

> When creating a derived column, you can either generate a new column
> or update an existing one. In the Column textbox, enter in the column
> you are creating. To override an existing column in your schema, you
> can use the column dropdown. To build the derived column's expression,
> click on the Enter expression textbox. You can either start typing
> your expression or open up the expression builder to construct your
> logic.

[image]

You should get help from this official [derived column transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column#create-and-update-columns) document to know how exactly derived column can be used.

Comment: Thank you. For now, the only solution I've found it's to use a Data Flow initialization.